# Send logger to I2C interface

Tags: i2c, display, python-3, headless

How can I pass a Python logger to the i2c interface? I bought a small 0.96" oled display and would like to use it on a headless raspi. Is there some way to just display everything thats raised by the logger?

If that not possible, can I use it for stdout?

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant.  You will need to find or write a library to display text on your OLED display.  You will have to trap all the logger output and send it to the library.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I capture the logger output? Do you know any libraries capable of this?

Comment: If it's for your own programs then you can create your own handler for the output https://realpython.com/python-logging/#using-handlers. If it's another program then possibly the `tail` command will help

Comment: Thanks for pointing out handlers. What kind of handler would I need to send the logger it via i2c?

Comment: The handler only captures the data from the Python script. I would ask the supplier how you control the screen via Python as different screens have different controllers.